# Assigning a char value to int variable work in Java

Tags: java, compilation, char, int

I came across this assignment while I was practicing

```
int I = '1'
```

I didn't understand how does it compile, can some please explain?

Answer (score -2):

First of all **[char is numeric](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)** type so it contains the code of letter (UTF-16 code units).

Then we have conversion rules for various types.
And this is [**widening primitive conversion**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

Comment: I believe this is actually correct.  But further explanation needed.  (I was not a down-voter).